# Ionic v3 Search Bar Filter through Object

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like to filter through my object results using various criteria

I am fairly new to IONIC and would like to accomplish this task of filtering the result

[image]

```js
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private searchServ : SearchService,) {
        this.allCreativeUsers();
    }

    allCreativeUsers() {

        this.searchServ.getAllCreatives().then(
            resp => {
                console.log( typeof (resp));
                console.log(resp);
                this.allPeople = resp;
            }
        );

    }

    filterItems(ev: any) {
        let val = ev.target.value;

        if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
            // Get The users from the Object Result and 
        }
    }
```

When I start typing someones name, I expect to be able to filter through the object and display the name of the person in the list.

[Like the do in the examples](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/components/#searchbar)

Comment: You should elaborate more your question so we can tackle down some kind of error, with what you have provided us it seems that you are looking for someone to complete a task that you should complete. Describe what have you tried, what failed, that kind of things is the input that we need.

Answer (score 0):

This will **filter** :

```
 filterdata:any

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private 
       searchServ : SearchService,) {
          this.allCreativeUsers();
         }

 allCreativeUsers() {

    this.searchServ.getAllCreatives().then(
        resp => {
            console.log( typeof (resp));
            console.log(resp);
            this.allPeople =  this.filterdata = resp;
        }
    );

 }

 filterItems(ev: any) {
    let val = ev.target.value;

    if (val && val.trim() !== '') {
        // Get The users from the Object Result and 

    this.allPeople =  this.filterdata.filter(r =>
       (<string>r.route).includes(val));

    }
  }
```